# How do I write to a file in Golang using a pointer to the C data?

Tags: c, go, ffmpeg, cgo

I'm writing an app for the windows platform using FFmpeg and it's golang wrapper goav, but I'm having trouble understanding how to use the C pointers to gain access to an array.

I'm trying to write the frame data, pointed to by a uint8 pointer from C, to a .ppm file in golang.

*Once I have this done, for proof of concept that FFmpeg is doing what I expect it to, I want to set the frames to a texture in OpenGl to make a video player with cool transitions; any pointers to do that nice and efficiently would be so very helpful! I'm guessing I need to write some shader code to draw the ppm as a texture...*

The [PPM file structure](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) looks pretty simple just the header and then a byte of data for each red, green and blue value of each pixel in the frame from top left to bottom right

I'm starting to understanding how to cast the pointers between C and Go types, but how can I access the data and write it in Go with the same result as C? In C I just have to set the pointer offset for the data and state how much of it to write:

```
for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);
}
```

I've stripped out all the relevant parts of the C code, the wrapper and my code, shown below:

C code - libavutil/frame.h

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct AVFrame {
#define AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS 8
    uint8_t *data[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS];
    int linesize[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS];
}
```

Golang goav wrapper

```
package avutil

/*
    #cgo pkg-config: libavutil
    #include <libavutil/frame.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"
import (
    "unsafe"
)

type Frame C.struct_AVFrame

func Data(f *Frame) *uint8 {
    return (*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer((*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&f.data))))
}
func Linesize(f *Frame) int {
    return int(*(*C.int)(unsafe.Pointer(&f.linesize)))
}
```

My Golang code

```
package main

import "github.com/giorgisio/goav/avutil"

func saveFrame(videoFrame *avutil.Frame, width int, height int, iFrame int) {
    var szFilename string
    var y int
    var file *os.File
    var err error

    szFilename = ""

    // Open file
    szFilename = fmt.Sprintf("frame%d.ppm", iFrame)

    if file, err = os.Create(szFilename); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error Reading")
    }

    // Write header
    fh := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height))
    file.Write(fh)
    var b byte = 0
    // Write pixel data
    for y = 0; y < height; y++ {
        d := avutil.Data(videoFrame) // d should be a pointer to the first byte of data
        l := avutil.Linesize(videoFrame)

        // I'm basically lost trying to figure out how to correctly write
        // this to a file, the file is created, but when I open it in GIMP
        // the image is mostly black with glitchy fuzz - so it's not being
        // written properly; the header seems to be ok, it knows the height
        // and width at least.

        data := make([]byte, l*3)

        ptr := unsafe.Pointer(d)
        for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
            datum := (*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(ptr) + (uintptr(i)+(uintptr(y)*uintptr(l)))*unsafe.Sizeof(*d)))
            data = append(data, *datum)
            //fmt.Println(*datum)
        }

        n, err := file.Write(data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error Writing:", szFilename, "-", n)
        }
    }

    file.Close()
}
```

So, how can I write to a file using a pointer to the data, like you can do in C, and get the same result?

The first frame should be black so all 0's but I'm getting a glitchy fuzz, so it must be accessing some random data

**Update:** My fix using a C function to save:

```
package avutil

/*
    #cgo pkg-config: libavutil
    #include <libavutil/frame.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    void SaveFrame(const char* location, AVFrame *pFrame, int width, int height) {
        FILE *pFile;
        int  y;

        // Open file
        pFile=fopen(location, "wb");
        if(pFile==NULL)
            return;

        // Write header
        fprintf(pFile, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);

        // Write pixel data
        for(y=0; y<height; y++)
            fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);

        // Close file
        fclose(pFile);
    }
    uint8_t* GetData(AVFrame *pFrame) {
        return pFrame->data[0];
    }
*/
import "C"
```

I updated the avutil file, in the goav wrapper package, with this save function at the top, then pass it the frame context so it can get the data pointer from it. I also added this Go function to that avutil file to call the C function

```
func SaveFrame(location string, f *Frame, width int, height int) {
    csLoc := C.CString(location)
    C.SaveFrame(csLoc, (*C.struct_AVFrame)(unsafe.Pointer(f)), C.int(width), C.int(height))
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(csLoc))
}
```

Comment: I got this working, saving my image, by writing a save file function in C and calling that from Go. It would still be interesting to see how this would work though. I think the problem is with the .Data() function call not returning the right thing, or my understanding of what to do with that to get the right type to pass around... which i really need now for gl.DrawPixels :/

Comment: Can you post what code you used? I am about to tackle this and will post something if I work it out

Comment: @Andrew sure, I added the working C save function that I'm using. This question has a better example of what I'm trying to do I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046388/how-to-pass-a-go-array-pointer-to-gldrawpixels?noredirect=1#comment87109166_50046388

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:
A C function allocated space and gave a pointer to that space and the size to read.
I solved it by doing:

```c
buffer := *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&content))
```

this transforms the pointer to a Golang byte array at the address of content.
`buffer` gets filled with data from `os.Read` and the C function handles the data.